# Field 'user_data' doesn't have a default value in CI 2.0.3

Tags: mysql, database, session-variables, codeigniter-2

I used CI's user guide to create my session table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

This error shows whenever I have `$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE` in my database.php

> Error Number: 1364
>
> Field 'user_data' doesn't have a default value
>
> INSERT INTO `sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`,
>   `last_activity`) VALUES ('2b92823888c4c5eb4b5b2ae25282ce9e',
>   '192.168.1.4', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1', 1317346730)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 327

However, I want to enforce strict SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference - *BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values*.

[The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html)

You should add `user_data` field in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the Session class in the system libraries. Add `'user_data' => ''` to the **userdata** array in **sess_create()** function.